# Can i have a repository on GitHub where a particualr user can only see the project and its issues, not the code and other issues?

Tags: github

I want to create a project under a github repo that will let us work with some external people. I don't want these people to be able to see all of the code associated with the repo or all of the issues associated with the repo. I only want them to be able to see and comment on the project and the issues and tasks that are in the project.

Comment: Probably not. Create a separate github repo for issue tracking.